# Gitlab (rails) "raw" file mime type for .svg files is 'text/plain'. Can it be configured to output as 'image/svg+xml'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

I've installed Gitlab on a local server for evaluation, and one key feature for me will be to have svg files display as images in the wiki.  I have it working if I drag a file into the wiki editor, which produces a url like so:

in wiki markdown:

```
![my svg diagram](http://server/my-group/my-project/uploads/90cdd5d76a05957ab7cf8854c55a38b8/my-diagram.svg)
```

results in page html:

```
<img src="http://server/my-group/my-project/uploads/90cdd5d76a05957ab7cf8854c55a38b8/my-diagram.svg" alt="my svg diagram">
```

and in order to get that to work, i had to edit `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/mime_types.rb` to add the line:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "image/svg+xml", :svg
```

and that's great if i want to drag an svg file into the wiki and have it stored in this 'uploads' section of the project, BUT, what i really want to do is display an svg image from the git repository.  (so that, for example a when a svg diagram changes, i dont have to hunt for it in the wiki, it will just pick it up from the master branch)

i have found that, for example, this is a link to a repo file:

```
http://server/my-group/my-project/raw/master/docsfolder/my-drawing.svg
```

however, the mime type apears to be `text/plain` for svg files referenced this way, and images with that as their `src` won't display.  Is there a way to make them `image/svg+xml`?  it seems the mime_types.rb config file does not affect this "raw" output.  or is there another way i can link to the repo file and get the specified mime type?

i also tried `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="...` and `<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="` and even iframe, but none of those work either.

Note:  it does work great for jpg images from the repo, just not svg images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.  seems the content type is set in ruby code in the raw_controller.rb file.  so i edit

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/controllers/projects/raw_controller.rb
```

change this:

```
  def get_blob_type
    if @blob.text?
      'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    else
      'application/octet-stream'
    end
  end
```

to something like this:

```
  def get_blob_type
    extn = File.extname(@blob.name).downcase
    if @blob.text?
      if extn == ".svg"
        'image/svg+xml'
      else 
        'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
      end
    else
      case extn
        when ".jpg", ".jpeg"
          'image/jpeg'
        when ".gif"
          'image/gif'
        when ".png"
          'image/png'
        when ".bmp"
          'image/bmp'
        when ".tiff"
           'image/tiff'
        else
          'application/octet-stream'
      end
    end
  end
```

then `sudo gitlab-ctrl restart`

now in my markdown, if i do this:

```
![my-diagram](http://server/my-group/my-project/raw/master/docsfolder/my-drawing.svg)
```

it works!

I've never used ruby before, so maybe there's a better way, but so far works for me.

Comment: Hello Chris, I think the reasoning why this is not enabled is security: In SVGs you may use Javascript, which now is delivered on behalf of your gitlab instance, so a bad guy or girl could capture your session.

Comment: That is interesting, I didn't know you could inject javascript into an svg file!  I did try this out on the system I used, modified as above, by injecting   `<script>alert('hi');</script>` before the closing svg tag in the file, and checked it in. The wiki still displayed the image, and did not execute the javascript. (IE and FF) Perhaps an img tag does not run the script?  It did execute the script if I view the raw file in it's own page tho.

Comment: as long as the markup image notation includes the `<img>` tag, it considers the svg as "static" svg... if you open the file in raw mode, probably the script will execute (didn't test it) ... but as I use gitlab in a controlled environment (few known users) we'll accept the security issue here. great solution. thanks!

Comment: When GitLab displays an SVG image standalone, it sanitizes it to remove the JavaScript (and apparently sometimes other text). But the inline images in Markdown just link to the raw URL and don't get the sanitiation. I've documented this in more detail [here](https://github.com/0cjs/git-repo-wiki/tree/master/inline-image).

Comment: The path in GitLab 11.x CE (Omnibus version) is:
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/helpers/blob_helper.rb

Comment: I am trying to do the same by changing the content-type for raw content on an internal GitLab 11.7-CE instance and it appears the solution is different from the original answer. I can't find any reference to `text/plain` in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/helpers/blob_helper.rb`. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

101chris's proposal works fine on 7.x, but needs some rework on gitlab 8.x.
Here's my update tested on 8.14.4:

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/helpers/blob_helper.rb :

```
  def safe_content_type(blob)
    if blob.text?
      case File.extname(blob.name).downcase
      when '.html'
        'text/html'
      when '.css'
        'text/css'
      when '.xml'
        'text/xml'
      when '.js'
        'application/javascript'
      else
        'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
      end
    elsif blob.image?
      blob.content_type
    else
      'application/octet-stream'
    end
  end
```

Comment: This code block seems to have disappeared in GitLab 11.7-CE. I can't find the equivalent in any other files so it looks like they have changed the code around quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It appears in GitLab 11.7-CE you need to update `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/helpers/workhorse_helper.rb` and change the following section:

```
def send_git_blob(repository, blob, inline: true)
  headers.store(*Gitlab::Workhorse.send_git_blob(repository, blob))

  headers['Content-Disposition'] = inline ? 'inline' : 'attachment'
  workhorse_set_content_type!

  render plain: ""
end
```

To the following (using ".html" as an example):

```
def send_git_blob(repository, blob, inline: true)
  headers.store(*Gitlab::Workhorse.send_git_blob(repository, blob))

  headers['Content-Disposition'] = inline ? 'inline' : 'attachment'

  if File.extname(@blob.name).downcase == '.html'
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
  else
    workhorse_set_content_type!
  end

  render plain: ""
end
```

As others have stated, the `Content-Type` is set to `text/plain` for security reasons as it protects you against XSS exploits. If you don't have a trusted closed set of users using GitLab then please don't do this.